# Windows service to WPF communication

Tags: c#, windows-services

***Context***
I have a scenario in which i have to read the file data from Directory (I/O) after 5 minutes and read the content of the file using TPL and after reading it i have to show the file content in a Grid to some Windows form ?

***Questions:***
 I have created the windows service and schedule it to run after every 5 minutes and it reads the files from the specified directory but now the problem is how i will show the data to grid because its a separate application written using WPF. Is there a way to get data from Windows service and show to windows form ?

Thanks

Comment: Use client/server programming through WCF.

Comment: Please see the marked duplicate for a basic overview of your options here. Note that the fact that you are dealing with a service and a WPF program are nearly irrelevant here, and that you are using TPL is completely irrelevant. The only thing that matters are techniques for transmitting data from one process to another; the only reason that it's at all relevant is that services have a mechanism for receiving commands that is in addition to other IPC options you have.